# Iterate String Java and select specific word

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following String:

```
[{"index":1,"image":"1234a.jpg","thumbnail":"1234a_t.jpg","medium":"1234a.jpg"},
{"index":2,"image":"43215256b.png","thumbnail":"43215256b_t.jpg","medium":"43215256b.jpg"}]
```

I would like to select only JPG name or the pngs like (1234a.jpg OR 43215256b.png) and ignore the rest of the String, How can I do that in Java?? I tried `substring` but it works not fine because the names of the JPGs are different.

Here a piece of my Java code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("imageID", c.getString("imageID"));
    map.put("image", c.getString("image"));
    MyArrList.add(map);
}
```

Where **image** is a database field that contains the **String** above, So I would like to select the JPGs names OR the PNGs names from the content of **c.getString("image")** I tried JSON but not worked, mabye have someone better Idea?? please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Perhaps a JSON parser?

Comment: I'd choose a JSON parser over a RegExp solution. Either Gson or Jackson are great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
    Modified Your Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
if(isValid(c.getString("image")))
{
map.put("imageID", c.getString("imageID"));
map.put("image", c.getString("image"));
MyArrList.add(map);
}
}
```

This is my Patch:

```
public boolean isValid(String value)
  {

      String jpgChk = "\\.jpg$";
      String pngChk = "\\.png$";
      Matcher jpgMatcher = Pattern.compile(jpgChk).matcher(value);
      Matcher pngMatcher = Pattern.compile(pngChk).matcher(value);
      if(jpgMatcher.find())
          return value.contains(".png")?false:true;
      else if (pngMatcher.find())
          return value.contains(".jpg")?false:true;
      else
          return false;
  }
```

This is long but immediate solution to your problem. If works accept it or we will try to minimize and optimize this one

Comment: I am not sure if isValid() is used at correct place in your code but the point is it will give the correct boolean value for your input string

Comment: Thanks, it works fine in my code, but how can I return the full name of the jpg (1234a.jpg) or the name of the png (43215256b.png)

Comment: @user3122166 What exactly are you getting from `c.getString("image")`? I guess that is giving you the full name of your jpg. Another thing, instead of calling _map.put()_ twice in every iteration. You can opt for `map.put(c.getString("imageID").c.getString("image"))`. Hope it works

Comment: Change the return type of the function to **String**. In place of true return the **value** as it is and instead of false return **null**. It will work and while calling the function try `if((data=isValid(c.getString("image"))!=null)` and do the rest as it is.
Reply if the answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regular JSON parser. If this is not possible use the regex `(?<=")\w+\.jpg(?=")` to find the names enclosed in quotes ("") ending with jpg.

When using a Java Pattern, you need double \ inside the String `"(?<=\")\\w+\\.jpg(?=\")"`

Answer (score 0):

Parse it in json format and check for each key if the value has a substring of jpg. if yes then you can use the whole value.

Comment: what if the name of the image contains "jpg" but in reality its a png? ;-)